# Weil reciprocity on abelian varieties and biextensions?

Tags: abelian-varieties, ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I was once told, by someone who would likely be right about such things, that the version of Weil reciprocity for abelian varieties (as in Lang, *Abelian Varieties*) should come out of consideration of biextensions. I'd be quite intrigued to know if this has ever been worked out and written down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lang's  reciprocity law and Poincar\'e-Mumford biextensions come together in the context of generalized N\'eron pairings

http://iopscience.iop.org/0025-5726/6/3/A03/pdf/0025-5726_6_3_A03.pdf

(Proof of Proposition 2 on p. 496 and  p. 502).

Comment: NÉRON PAIRING AND QUASICHARACTERS

1972 Math. USSR Izv. 6 491

Access restricted: you will need to login or make a payment to access the full text of this article.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. However, the original Russian version is available for free (see pp. 502 and 508--509 of)
http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=2308&option_lang=eng
http://www.mathnet.ru/links/07870c75a71989615a88f79957d8d509/im2308.pdf